# How do you stop a remote router actor whose supervisor is local in Akka.net?

Tags: akka.net

I have created an Akka.net actor system with these actors

1) A top level 'Supervisor' actor:

```
    _supervisor = _actorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create<Supervisor>(), "Supervisor");
```

2) A child actor 'WorkerRouter' defined as a round-robin actor supervising 'WorkerActors':

```
    _props = Props.Create<WorkerActor>().WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(3));
    _workerRouter = Context.ActorOf(_props, "WorkerRouter");
    Context.Watch(_workerRouter);
```

I have observed inconsistent behaviour with remote deployment when stopping the WorkerRouter.

- When running locally the behaviour is as I expect when calling:

  ```
      Context.Stop(_workerRouter);
  ```

  This stops each of the WorkerActors and their PostStop hooks fire.  DeathWatch kicks in and the Supervisor receives a Terminated message for WorkerRouter.  I can then recreate the WorkerRouter.
- If I add the HOCON configuration below to deploy Supervisor (and WorkerRouter) remotely the behaviour is still as above and as expected:

  ```
      deployment {
        /Supervisor {
          remote = "akka.tcp://ActorSystem@127.0.0.1:8091"
        }
  ```
- However, my original intention was to keep Supervisor local and deploy WorkerRouter remotely.  With the configuration below, the behaviour is not as I expect - the WorkerActors still shutdown, but Supervisor no longer receives a Terminated message for WorkerRouter, and therefore I can't recreate the WorkerRouter (attempts to do so result in an InvalidActorNameException because the actor has not terminated and the name is still in use):

  ```
      deployment {
        /Supervisor/WorkerRouter {
          remote = "akka.tcp://ActorSystem@127.0.0.1:8091"
        }
  ```

Is this by design or a bug in Akka.net?

Comment: How it works if you will send PoisonPill to that actor?

Comment: The result is the same with PoisonPill.

Comment: On second thoughts I think the result was the same with PoisonPill - however this wasn't what I required because I wanted to stop processing messages in the router's mailbox.

Comment: the gol is to stop processing messages instead of stopping/killing an actor?

Comment: Yes, stop the router actor so that its children stopped processing (converting queues of files),  then recreate it so it can process a new batch.